# Group sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to have an only query with 2 queries but i don't know how to start...
My queries count the positive/negative votes for a comment.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS votes_no FROM comments_votes WHERE vote = 0 AND id_comment = 1
SELECT COUNT(id) AS votes_no FROM comments_votes WHERE vote = 1 AND id_comment = 1
```

I set vars to put negative and positives votes : `$votes_no` and `$votes_yes`

Then i have a final var : `$votes_calc = $votes_yes - $votes_no;`

How can i get the number of votes_yes, votes_no and votes_calc in only one query?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is the value in the 'vote' column always 0 or 1?

Comment: What does a vote_yes query look like?  What is the 'vote' column value representing?

Comment: @IvanGoneKrazy 1 or -1
@galford13x The column vote is an integer (1 or -1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select votes_no, votes_yes, votes_yes-votes_no as votes_calc
from (select sum(case when vote = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as votes_no,
             sum(case when vote = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as votes_yes
      from comments_votes
      where id_comment = 1) a
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select vote,count(id)
from Comment_votes
group by vote
WHERE id_comment = 1
with rollup
```

The with Rollup will add a row with a NULL value in the vote column and the total in the second column

Answer (score 0):

I merge the query getting the comments and the comments votes and it seems to work :)

```
SELECT a.*, nb_votes, votes_yes-votes_no AS votes_calc
FROM comments AS a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id_comment, COUNT(id) AS nb_votes,
    SUM(CASE WHEN vote = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS votes_no,
    SUM(CASE WHEN vote = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS votes_yes
    FROM comments_votes GROUP BY id_comment
) AS c ON (a.id = c.id_comment)
WHERE a.status = 'approved' AND a.id_post = 1 ORDER BY a.time ASC
```

Thanks for your answers :)